# Catch Regex too complicated when splitting a string in salesforce

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, string, try-catch

I have created a function wherein I split a string from the csv `filecsvAsString.split('\n')`
. It is working when the string is not so big. But when I try to split a very large string, an error will occur

> regex too complicated

what I want to do is to catch if an error occur during the split process. How will I do it ? I've tried to use try and catch but the problem still occur. Is there any other possible solution?

Comment: Fields can contain embedded line breaks in csv files.

Comment: @martin I didn't understand your purpose. Actually I want to use split because I only need to get the first row. But my main issue here is to trap the possible error occured.

Comment: That was just a warning that with using split('\n'), you won't get the entire line if one of the fields has a line break in it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not a catch per say (IIRC you cannot catch it, especially if `Catch Exception` did not work) but will solve the problem of regex to complex, use a custom iterator:

**CLASS**

```
public with sharing class Utility_RowIterator implements Iterator<String>, Iterable<String>
{
   private String m_Data;
   private Integer m_index = 0;
   private String m_rowDelimiter = '\n';
    
   public Utility_RowIterator(String fileData)
   {
      m_Data = fileData; 
   }
   public Utility_RowIterator(String fileData, String rowDelimiter)
   {
      m_Data = fileData; 
      m_rowDelimiter = rowDelimiter;
   }
    
   public Boolean hasNext()
   {
      return m_index < m_Data.length() ? true : false;
   }
   public String next()
   {     
      Integer key = m_Data.indexOf(m_rowDelimiter, m_index);
       
      if (key == -1)
        key = m_Data.length();
             
      String row = m_Data.subString(m_index, key);
      m_index = key + 1;
      return row;
   }
   public Iterator<String> Iterator()
   {
      return this;   
   }
}
```

**CODE**

```
Utility_RowIterator r = New Utility_RowIterator(csv,'\n'); //Replace \n with whatever delineates your row

String firstRow;
if(r.hasNext()) firstRow = r.next();
```

**TEST CLASS**
(Provided by @KateFedchenko)

```
@isTest static void testUtilityRowIterator() {
    String csv = '"FirstName", "LastName"\n"TestName1", "Test1"\n"TestName2", "Test2"';
    List<String> names = new List<String>();
    UtilityRowIterator rowIterator = new UtilityRowIterator(csv, '\n');
    Iterator<String> iterator = rowIterator.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        names.add(iterator.next());
    }
    System.assertEquals('"TestName1", "Test1"', names[1]);
}
```

Comment: I've tried this , and i think this is the answer of my problem. Thank you...

Comment: @Hope - Glad it worked for you......

Comment: Eric - although I voted this up _?years?_ ago, I had occasion to need this again and it was super helpful

Comment: Eric - your solution was incredibly helpful. I am looking to parse a CSV file and all of the CSVIterators I found did not account for the -1 key value that your code accounts for when firing next(). Much appreciated!!

Comment: Eric provided an excellent solution to the problem that was solved thanks to his code. I do not have enough reputation to comment him, but I want to contribute at least a little bit with the test method for his class that covers 100% of lines.

Comment: @KateFedchenko Your answer got flagged for not being an answer, so I moved the text to a comment for you and edited Eric's answer to add your test class. Great contribution, please do stick around :)

Comment: This code works when the column values doesn’t contain commas . When it does I’m running into issues leading to more columns than expected when the csvRow string is split based on commas. I am not sure how to tweak it to address the column value having commas in it . Can someone help

Comment: the last value in each row had a hard return at the end of it; I changed

`String row = m_Data.subString(m_index, key);`

to

`String row = m_Data.subString(m_index, key).trim();`

Comment: I did something similar to this in the past when processing very large CSV files, kudos.  Also it is unfortunately the case that you CANNOT catch `regex too complicated` errors.