# Parsing csv in apex

Tags: apex

From internet found this article and found usefull, but I am seeing it will give only first line of the line, how to parse the file and get all the lines in a list. Below is the link which @eric has wrote/answered
[Catch Regex too complicated when splitting a string in salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/85048/catch-regex-too-complicated-when-splitting-a-string-in-salesforce/85050#85050)

Answer (score 0):

In @Eric answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/85050/45062) , he has used `if` condition, try to use `while` in your case and that should iterate the whole file.

**NOTE** : I have not tried this.

UPDATE:

Just tried it and `while` works fine.

```
List<ContentVersion> contentVersion = [
        SELECT
                VersionData
        FROM ContentVersion
        WHERE ContentDocumentId = '*********'
];


Utility_RowIterator r = new Utility_RowIterator(contentVersion.get(0).VersionData.toString(), '\n'); //Replace \n with whatever delineates your row

List<String> allRow = new List<String>();
while (r.hasNext()) {
    allRow.add(r.next());
}

System.debug(allRow.size());
```

Comment: Note: this is not the proper way to parse a CSV. It does not parse multi-line cells correctly.