# Trying to String.split on new line after matched substring

Tags: apex, string, regular-expressions

I have a script that is hitting a System.LimitException: Regex too complicated Error and so to combat this I've come up with a solution to chunk up the string and then do the regex to the chunks so that it wont hit that limit.

Here is the problem, finding a clean way to cut up the document so that it still works.

Originally I was cutting the string up by every new line String.split('\r\n|\r|\n') so it could then digest it line by line (but if the document was too long it hit the above limit) so now im targeting some text and then want to get the next new line that comes after so it will be a clean cut. So really I need to figure out the regex for the String.split() method to match the substring I give it then find the newline after that to split on.

so for example:

If myString = '22:45:07.0 (1307331)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[139]|Bytes:6 /n
22:45:07.0 (1328106)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:27 /n
22:45:07.0 (1358441)|METHOD_ENTRY| [2]|01p4x000006c0jb|AttachmentTriggerLogic_Test.AttachmentTriggerLogic_Test() /n
22:45:07.0 (1374280)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[2] /n
22:45:07.0 (1383574)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[2] /n
22:45:07.0 (1386012)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[4] /n'

and I target substring ')|METHOD_ENTRY|', how then would i be able to find the newline after it?

The new line regex im using now is: '\r\n|\r|\n'

I was thinking of using String.indexOf(substring, index) but I need it to be String.indexOf(REGEX, index) and when I try it using a regex it returns -1 as it cant find the regex (since thats not a sub string lol) I just need to find the position on of the end of line after the firstIndex I match.

so really after trying a few things im down to just coming up with a regex for the String.split() method that matches the substring ')|METHOD_ENTRY|' and then finds the end of the line after that to split on?

Let me know if anyone has any ideas? or other ways?

Comment: Have you tried the answer in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/85048/catch-regex-too-complicated-when-splitting-a-string-in-salesforce

Comment: no but i'll try it in the morning, thanks @NickCook it also raises a potential issue (in one of the comments) of what if there is a /n in the logs that could trigger my split when it isnt an actual new line in the log etc.. ugh